# Yii CDbCriteria add column

Tags: mysql, yii

I created a criteria:

```
        $ids = array(1,2,3);
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->select = 'SUM(quantity) as quan';
        $criteria->with = array('order');
        $criteria->condition="order.customer = ".Yii::app()->user->id." AND order.status_id <> 4 AND order.status_id <> 3 AND order.type = 0";
        $criteria->addInCondition("product_id", $ids);
        $order_prod = OrderProduct::model()->find($criteria);
```

but when i run this i got error:

> 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'als.t.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT SUM(quantity) as quan, `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `order`.`id` AS `t1_c0`, `order`.`phone` AS `t1_c1`, `order`.`email` AS `t1_c2`.

In criteria select i use only sum of quantity.

Comment: it this full query? Show your full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Disable `only_full_group_by`

try this `sql`

```
  SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get only quantity sum from OrderProduct table. So, it'll be better not to use active record, but write simple command with query, something like this:

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('
    SELECT SUM(t.quantity) as quan
    FROM order_product t 
    LEFT JOIN order ON order.ID = t.order_id 
    WHERE 
        order.customer = :userId AND 
        order.status_id NOT IN (3,4) AND 
        order.type = 0 AND 
        t.product_id IN (1,2,3)
')->queryScalar([
    ':userId' => Yii::app()->user->id,
]);
```

Here "db" is the name of your CDbConnection component. OrderProduct table name and join condition may be different in your system.